# ASP.NET inline scripting

Tags: c#, asp.net, scripting, inline

I have a DateTime object that I need to print in a custom gridlike control.
The type of the data I want to print is a date in the format dd-mm-yyyy.
This value can be either filled or blank.
If it's filled it will be parsed into a `DateTime` and then printed as the default `ToString`.

For each row, I can use

```
<CellTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.Value %>"></asp:Literal>
</CellTemplate>
```

But this prints the default long version of the date. I'd like the format from `ToShortDateString()`.

So I tried modifying to:

```
<CellTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Container.Value).ToShortTimeString()%>"></asp:Literal>
</CellTemplate>
```

This works as intended.

Now I have a problem with empty dates,

```
Convert.ToDateTime()
```

On an empty string, it will print the default DateTime.

Is there a way that I can fashion an If-Statement in my aspx code, to only perform `Convert.ToDateTime`, if it's not an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Container.Value.Length > 0 ? Convert.ToDateTime(Container.Value).ToShortTimeString() : ""
```

You should also be able to pass `Container.Value` to any method in scope that you've defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a protected method in your code behind which does the checking for you

```
protected static string ConvertDate(object date) {
    if (date == null)
       return string.Empty;
    return Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToShortTimeString();
}
```

Comment: You can do this and avoid boxing by using DateTime? (nullable)

Comment: This is a great idea. And ultimately my fallback solution. I would however like to learn how to do this purely inside the apsx page.

Comment: It depends on what type of object is returned from the data source

Comment: I believe the type is a string

Comment: You should be able to use marxidad's answer. Try putting his script block straight into the cell template without the literal <CellTemplate>
 <%# Container.Value.Length > 0 ? Convert.ToDateTime(Container.Value).ToShortTimeString() : "" %>
</CellTemplate>

Comment: You are correct. The <Literal>, for unknown reasons, did not allow the ? : statement. Without it, it now works perfectly fine

Comment: The problem was with the quotes from Text="".

In your script block you also use quotes, you can't nest quotes like that.